# Definite integration vs differentiation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a maybe obvious question
is this true?

$$
r = \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta f(\theta) e^{i\theta}
\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta}(r) = 0
$$

Or should I differentiate first, and then do the definit integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite integral $r = \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta f(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ is a number provided that it's defined.

$\dfrac{d}{d\theta} r = 0$ because you are differentiating a number $r$ that doesn't change with $\theta$ with respect to a variable $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Since that integral doesn't depend upon $r$, if you differentiate it with respect to $r$, you ger $0$.